# Windows Store Apps App Bar Buttons Text Binding

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I have an App Bar with some buttons like this

```
<Page.BottomAppBar>
    <AppBar x:Name="bottomAppBar" Padding="10,10,10,10"  >
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
            <Button Style="{StaticResource ReadAppBarButtonStyle}"  >
            </Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </AppBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>
```

I want  to bind the button text to a selected item property of a **ListView** and use an **IValueConverter**.

I found that the button text is to be set using AutomationProperties.Name

how can I bind this property through **XAML** or **Code**.

Thanks

Comment: So what's the problem? just set the binding to AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=list}"

Comment: I did so but the text appears blank

Comment: How can I change AutomationProperties.Name programmatically ?

Comment: AutomationProperties.SetName(element, value)?

Comment: I wonder if there is a problem with separate name scopes between the children of a Page and children of the Page.BottomAppBar property which would prevent ElementName bindings. Would putting the AppBar as a child control of the layout Grid instead of Page.BottomAppBar make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right, for some reason the following doesn't work, although the same binding works just fine you use it for e.g. `Text` property of a `TextBox`:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource SkipBackAppBarButtonStyle}" AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=List}" />
```

I did manage to get it work by using a property in the view model and binding to it both `ListView.SelectedItem` and `AutomationProperties.Name`:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Strings}" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedString, Mode=TwoWay}" />
<!-- ... -->
<Button Style="{StaticResource SkipBackAppBarButtonStyle}" 
        AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding SelectedString}" />
```

`SelectedString` should be a property in a view model implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        Strings = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
            Strings.Add("Value " + i);
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> Strings { get; set; }

    private string _selectedString;
    public string SelectedString
    {
        get { return _selectedString; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _selectedString) return;
            _selectedString = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I chose another solution, which is to check the list selected item at the AppBar_Opened, Event handler